# Is the device connected to WIFI or not?

Tags: iphone, wifi, symbols, reachability, system-configuration

I need to know if the device is connected via WIFI or not. This should be pretty simple, but I broke my neck on the sample code apple supply [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html). I can't seem to get it to work in my own app. Is this not the only thing I need to do?

IN H:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

    @class Reachability;

    @interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

        Reachability* wifiReach;
    }
```

IN M:
I just try to call the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];
```

But compiling results in:

WARNING: no '+reachabilityForLocalWiFi' method found

ERROR:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-Reachability in FirstViewController.o - Symbol not found

Seeing this, I'm probably doing something really wrong here. Thought this would be a simple task. Damn my good ideas.

Comment: In your .m file, are you importing Reachability.h?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

and

```
- (BOOL)networkCheck{
    Reachability *curReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    [curReach release];
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");
            return true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

then `[self networkCheck]` will return true if connected to wifi. I use the reachability code too, and this works perfectly in all my applications.

Comment: Ups. You are absolutely right. I forgot to import the header, so of cause Xcode couldn't figure things out. Now it works. Btw, isn't there a leak in your code. Where does curReach gets released??

Comment: oops... :p *looks embarassed*

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure why its even retained in the first place. I'm sure there was a good reason at the time. :/

Comment: Or is it released somewhere? If I autorelease it, the app crashes. Have you tried it without the first retain? Or with the code you have written now?

Comment: if you just do `Reachability *curReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];` without the retain what happens then? That will be autoreleased automatically, so you don't have to release it then.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have:

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

in your .m file?